# Delete all lines containing double forward slashes

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

I have a sample text file like which contains lines like below:

```
/home0/abc/xyz/Example1.java:               //  log.error("error" , exception);
/home0/abc/xyz/Example2.java:                   log.error("error" , exception);
/home0/abc/xyz/Example3.java:               //  log.error("error" , exception);
/home0/abc/xyz/Example4.java:                   log.error("error" , exception);
```

How can i delete all the lines containing double forward slashes (that is lines containing comments )in shell script.

My final output should like below:

```
/home0/abc/xyz/Example2.java:                   log.error("error" , exception);
/home0/abc/xyz/Example4.java:                   log.error("error" , exception);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use grep,

```
grep -v '//' file
```

From `grep --help`,

```
-v, --invert-match        select non-matching lines
```

Through sed,

```
sed '/\/\//d' file
```

The above sed command would delete those lines which contain two forward slashes. Syntax of the above sed is, `sed '/regex/d' file`. Because `/` is used as sed delimiters, escape the slashes present in your regex in-order to match a literal forward slash.

Through awk,

```
awk '!/\/\//' file
```

`!` negates the pattern and forces the awk to print the lines which won't contain `//`

Comment: Hey Avinash, If i use grep -v '//' file, Its just printing the matching lines on the console, not deleting from the source file.

Comment: yep then you could redirect the output to another file `grep -v '//' infile > outfile`, likewise the same for awk also. But in sed you could do an in-place edit using `-i` param, like `sed -i '/\/\//d' file`

Comment: Thanks Avinash. I redirected output to another file. Thats much better

Answer (score 3):

In a vi or vim editor, do this:

`:g/\/\//d`

which is: *colon, g, slash, back-slash, slash, back-slash, slash, slash, d*

Comment: Explanation might help others to understand.

Comment: `:` for command header, `g` for execution of the following command on all lines, `/.../` for a pattern matching, `\/\/` is the pattern to find, `d` for delete the line

Answer (score 3):

In grep you should use -v option like this

```
grep -v pattern filename
```

-v -used for invert the pattern matching.

In sed

```
  sed '/\/\//d' filename
```

d -for delete the pattern matched line.